# RES keep growing but there is no GC shown via jstat?

Tags: centos, java, memory-leak

We have a java application running on Centos 6.4 what we notice is RES value is cross 400m which is more then the allocated max heap that is 256m. According to jstat results as below there is no GC happening is this alarming situation? What proactive measures can be taken I have also run the heap analysis via MAT.

```
Timestamp         S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
      2331438.3  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331443.3  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331448.4  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331453.4  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331458.4  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331463.4  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331468.4  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331473.4  56.95   0.00  63.24  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331478.4  56.95   0.00  63.24  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331483.4  56.95   0.00  63.78  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331488.4  56.95   0.00  63.78  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331493.4  56.95   0.00  63.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331498.4  56.95   0.00  63.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337



MAT results.

Problem Suspect 1 

One instance of "org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioWorker" loaded by "org.rzo.yajsw.boot.WrapperClassLoader @ 0xf0002a50" occupies 49,451,672 (75.12%) bytes. 

Keywords
org.rzo.yajsw.boot.WrapperClassLoader @ 0xf0002a50
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioWorker

Problem Suspect 2

The class "java.lang.ref.Finalizer", loaded by "<system class loader>", occupies 10,408,112 (15.81%) bytes. 

Keywords
java.lang.ref.Finalizer
```

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that RES memory does not match heap memory as heap is only part of jvm process memory.See [JVM Memory Structure](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/sizes.jsp). Is that the only problem?